# ExportAsService -

Tags: angular, pdf-generation

I am using ExportAsService to generate and download a pdf in my system (working)
But how to use this library and send the generated pdf to an api instead of downloading?
Is it possible to do that with exportasService.
If not kindly refer if any other library supports the requirement thanks in advance